# Отфильтровать таблицу по выбраным чекбоксам, изменение метода

Tags: javascript, jquery

я написал метод который фильтрует таблицу по чекбоксам, выглядит он так:

```
this.filterTableByColumn = function (filters) {
  if (!this.form[this.currentColumn])
    return;

  var table = this.table;

  filterTable();

  // Functions
  function filterTable() {
    table.find('tr:visible').each(function () {
      var row = $(this);

      if (!row.hasClass("table-row-header")) {
        for (var index in filters) {
          if (filters[index].length) {
            var row = $(this);

            rowMustBeShown(row, filters) ? row.show() : row.hide();
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }

  function rowMustBeShown(row, filters) {
    var condition = false;

    for (var index in filters) {
      if (filters[index].length)
        condition = checkRowByFilter(filters[index], row, index);
    }

    return condition;
  }

  function checkRowByFilter(filter, row, index) {
    var condition2 = false;
    var colIndex = index - 1;

    if (filter.length) {
      filter.forEach(function (filterItem) {

        var cell = row.find("td:eq(" + colIndex + "):contains(" + filterItem + ")");

        if (cell.text().indexOf(filterItem) >= 0)
          condition2 = true;
      });
    }

    return condition2;
  }
}
```

В параметр filters мне приходит обьект с двумя подмасивами чекбоксов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример обьекта:

```
{
    5: ["ended", "confirmed"]
    7: ["on-line"]
}
```

В случае с примером массива выше, метод выводит все строки с ячейками "on-line", "ended", "confirmed". Я хочу переделать так чтобы метод, например, вывел все строки с ячейкой "on-line", у которых также есть ячейки "ended", "confirmed". У меня уже закончились идеи. Может ли кто-то помочь?

Comment: А Вы хорошо Ваш метод протестировали? На мой взгляд, он будет выводить только строки с последней ячейкой в объекте. В вашем примере `online`. В функции `rowMustBeShown` значение `condition` определяется последним элементом цикла. Делайте `break` из цикла, если `condition`, полученная как результат `checkRowByFilter`, является `true`